# Merge Sort Complexity Confusion

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, big-o

Can someone explain to me in plain english how Merge Sort is O(n*logn). I know that the 'n' comes from the fact that it takes n appends to merge two sorted lists of size n/2. What confuses me is the log. If we were to draw a tree of the function calls of running Merge Sort on a 32 element list, then it would have 5 levels. Log2(32)= 5. That makes sense, however, why do we use the levels of the tree, rather than the actual function calls and merges in the Big O definition ?
In this [diagram](http://www.studytonight.com/data-structures/images/merge-sort.png) we can see that for an 8 element list, there are 3 levels. In this context, Big O is trying to find how the number of operations behaves as the input increases, my question is how are the levels (of function calls) considered operations?

Comment: Because you need to touch every element on every level of the tree in order to merge. Read [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Analysis) for a more thorough analysis.

Comment: You could consider the diagram as a model of bottom up merge sort, starting at the bottom, with n "sorted" lists of size 1, ending up at the top with one sorted list of size 8. Assuming a second working buffer, each pass  moves 8 elements, and it takes 3 passes to do the sort. The first pass results in list of size 2, the second pass in list of size 4, the third pass in a list of size 8. For a 2-way merge sort, the number of passes is ⌈ log2(n) ⌉  (where ⌈ ⌉ is ceiling or round up function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The levels of function calls are considered like this(in the book [introduction to algorithms](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms Chapter 2.3.2):

> We reason as follows to set up the recurrence for T(n), the worst-case running time of merge sort on n numbers. Merge sort on just one element takes constant time. When we have n > 1 elements, we break down the running time as follows.
>
> **Divide:** The divide step just computes the middle of the subarray, which takes constant time. Thus, D(n) =  Θ(1).
>
> **Conquer:** We recursively solve two subproblems, each of size n/2, which contributes 2T(n/2) to the running time.
>
> **Combine:** We have already noted that the MERGE procedure on an n-element subarray takes time  Θ(n), and so C(n) = Θ(n).
>
> When we add the functions D(n) and C(n) for the merge sort analysis, we are adding a function that is Θ(n) and a function that is Θ(1). This sum is a linear function of n, that is, Θ(n). Adding it to the 2T(n/2) term from the “conquer” step gives the recurrence for the worst-case running time T(n) of merge sort:
>
> T(n) = Θ(1), if n = 1; T(n) = 2T(n/2) + Θ(n), if n > 1.

Then using the recursion tree or the master theorem, we can calculate:

T(n) = Θ(nlgn).

Answer (score 0):

Simple analysis:-
Say length of array is n to be sorted.
Now every time it will be divided into half.
So,  see as under:-
          n
   n/2               n/2
n/4   n/4          n/4   n/4
............................
1 1 1 ......................

As you can see height of tree will be logn( 2^k = n; k = logn)
At every level sum will be n. (n/2 +n/2 = n, n/4+n/4+n/4+n/4 = n).

So finally levels = logn and every level takes n
combining we get nlogn

Now regarding your question, how levels are considered operations, consider as under:-
array 9, 5, 7
suppose its split into 9,5 and 7
for 9,5 it will get converted to 5,9 (at this level one swap required)
then in upper level 5,9 and 7  while merging gets converted to 5,7,9
(again at this level one swap required).

In worst case on any level number operations can be O(N) and number of levels logn. Hence nlogn.

For more clarity try to code merge sort, you will be able to visualise it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take your 8-item array as an example. We start with `[5,3,7,8,6,2,1,4]`.

As you noted, there are three passes. In the first pass, we merge 1-element subarrays. In this case, we'd compare 5 with 3, 7 with 8, 2 with 6, and 1 with 4. Typical merge sort behavior is to copy items to a secondary array. So every item is copied; we just change the order of adjacent items when necessary. After the first pass, the array is `[3,5,7,8,2,6,1,4]`.

On the next pass, we merge two-element sequences. So `[3,5]` is merged with `[7,8]`, and `[2,6]` is merged with `[1,4]`. The result is `[3,5,7,8,1,2,4,6]`. Again, every element was copied.

In the final pass the algorithm again copies every item.

There are log(n) passes, and at every pass all n items are copied. (There are also comparisons, of course, but the number is linear and no more than the number of items.) Anyway, if you're doing n operations log(n) times, then the algorithm is O(n log n).